# Understanding how layer information fields are set and filled out in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tile-map-service

I have developed a python API to serve pregenerated tiles for a local area of interest. Then I created a simple map using **Openlayers** to render tiles on OSM basemap.

The API is running and responding smoothly and provides the tiles once users do pan and zoom in/out. Using `extent` in creating the `TileLayer` (`ol.tile.layer`) I could also manage to stop sending requests to the server for the areas located out of the BBOX of source data.

Now I am trying to use this link in **QGIS** application by defining a new **XYZ Tiles** layer. When I create the layer and add it to the map, **QGIS** starts sending requests to my local TMS server, no matter what is the current extent and zoom are!

After doing search and checking **QGIS** settings, I found the following information about my custom layer.
[image]
And I can see that the extent was already set globally.

**Questions**

1. Where does this data come from?
2. Can these settings (e.g. `extent`) be set somehow using my local server (e.g. by creating an endpoint)?